# Why attribute tensor_dot is not found in tensorly

Tags: python, tensorly

Consider the following code, where I define a function to calculate the Kronecker product of matrices. The goal, is to use `tensor_dot` from the `tensorly` library for a tensor extrapolation algorithm.

```
import numpy as np
import numpy.linalg as la
#%pip install tensorly
import pandas as pd
import tensorly as tl

import warnings

from scipy.stats import norm

def matrix_outer (A, B, C ) :
    
    """
    Calculates Kronecker product of Matrices A, B, C
    """
    n_A = A.shape[0]
    
    n_B = B.shape[0]
    
    n_C = C.shape[0]
    
    k = A.shape[1]
    
    tensor = tl.zeros(shape=(n_A, n_B, n_C))
    
    for i in range(k):
        coef_a = A[:,i]
        coef_b = B[:,i]
        coef_c = C[:,i]
        tensor += tl.tenalg.tensor_dot(tl.tenalg.tensor_dot(coef_a, coef_b).reshape(n_a, n_B), coef_c).reshape(n_A, n_B, n_C)
                
    return tensor
    
"""
Okay now we've defined our functions.

The next step is data generation.
"""

# Tensor size

R = 4

n_user = 160 # We have 100 units/users. This is a marketing application.

n_prod = 120 # Sales data, for example, of different products

n_time = 100 # Here are our time periods.


# Auxiliary function for normalizing vectors
# https://sparrow.dev/numpy-norm/

normalize_vec = lambda vec: vec/la.norm(vec)

"""
User participation is shown in matrix A.
"""

user_index = np.linspace(-3, 3, num=n_user)

user_bell = normalize_vec(norm.pdf(user_index, loc = 0, scale = 0.5))

user_bell2 = np.roll(user_bell,120)

user_bell3 = np.roll(user_bell,80 )

user_bell4 = np.roll(user_bell,40 )

A = np.c_[user_bell, user_bell2, user_bell3, user_bell4]

"""
Product participation is shown in matrix B.
"""

productl = normalize_vec(np.repeat([1, 2, 3 , 4], 30, axis=0))
product2 = np.roll(productl, 90 )
product3 = np.roll(productl, 60 )
product4 = np.roll(productl, 30 )

B = np.c_[productl, product2, product3, product4]



tseriesl = normalize_vec(0.3*np.sin(np.arange(0, n_time*2, step=2*np.pi/7))[0:n_time]+0.5)
tseries2 = normalize_vec(np.linspace(0, 1, n_time))
tseries3 = normalize_vec(np.repeat([0, 1], n_time/2, axis=0))
tseries4 = normalize_vec(np.repeat([1, 0], [n_time/4, 3*n_time/4], axis=0))
C = np.c_[tseriesl, tseries2, tseries3, tseries4]

#Aggregate Matrices and denoise them
np.random.seed(1512)
data = matrix_outer(A,B, C)
data_noisy= data + np.random.normal(loc=0,scale=0.5*tl.mean(datas), size=(data.shape))
```

On the second to last line, Python throws an exception, saying

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 14, in matrix_outer
AttributeError: module 'tensorly.tenalg' has no attribute 'tensor_dot'
(1 line skipped)
```

When I look at [the official documentation](http://tensorly.org/stable/modules/generated/tensorly.tenalg.tensor_dot.html) for `tensorly`, `tensorly.tenalg` does in fact have such an attribute. Why might Python be having this issue? Perhaps I should use the version of `tensorly` from GitHub and not from `pip`? If it helps at all, my code comes from [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1hZnFQGwFl4uMehLqAm0fDSOR4J84lcPi/view), where code block 4 defines the function of interest.

Answer (score 0):

We switched to `tensordot` (instead of `tensor_dot`) to follow the NumPy API, with the addition of optional batch-modes, see doc here: http://tensorly.org/dev/modules/generated/tensorly.tenalg.tensordot.html#tensorly.tenalg.tensordot

As a side note, TensorLy also includes a [Kronecker](http://tensorly.org/dev/modules/generated/tensorly.tenalg.kronecker.html#tensorly.tenalg.kronecker) function in the tenalg submodule that you can directly use to take the Kronecker product of a list of matrices.